# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: if

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, sqlplus

i have some trouble here.. i think i dont make any mistake here.. but my PL/SQL say this error to me..

**PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:if**

this is my code below, please help me to solve this problem :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_tb_goods
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
ON tb_sales_details
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_gq NUMBER;
BEGIN 
IF INSERTING THEN 
SELECT quantity 
INTO v_gq
FROM tb_goods
WHERE goods_id = :NEW.goods_id;
UPDATE tb_goods 
SET quantity = v_gq - :NEW.quantity 
WHERE goods_id = :NEW.goods_id;
END IF;
IF UPDATING THEN 
SELECT quantity 
INTO v_gq
FROM tb_goods
WHERE goods_id = :OLD.goods_id;
UPDATE tb_goods 
SET quantity = v_gq + :OLD.quantity 
WHERE goods_id = :OLD.goods_id;
SELECT quantity 
INTO v_gq
FROM tb_goods
WHERE goods_id = :NEW.goods_id;
UPDATE tb_goods 
SET quantity = v_gq - :NEW.quantity 
WHERE goods_id = :NEW.goods_id;
END IF;
IF DELETING THEN
SELECT quantity 
INTO v_gq
FROM tb_goods
WHERE goods_id = :OLD.goods_id;
UPDATE tb_goods 
SET quantity = v_gq + :OLD.quantity 
WHERE goods_id = :OLD.goods_id;
ENDIF;
END;
/
```

Thankyou..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `ENDIF;` but `END IF;` (at the very end of that code).

Comment: thank you so much :D :D how can i use "ENDIF" and i dont see it.. thank you brother

Comment: No problem, it happens :)